# Getting "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')" on mac m1 but not on windows

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

After updating `dotnet` from `2.1` to `6` in my project, I had to replace `System.Data.SqlClient` by `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`.

When project was on `dotnet 2.1` and `System.Data.SqlClient` was remaining, every thing was working well (on mac m1 and windows). but after updating project to `dotnet 6` and `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`, when run project on windows platform, every thing is ok, but on mac m1 I get the `Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')` error.

I get the error when trying to work with methods of `EF Core` and `Linq` such as `SaveChanges` or `Where` methods.

this is callstack:

```
at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Where[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SSRP.SendUDPRequest(String browserHostname, Int32 port, Byte[] requestPacket, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean allIPsInParallel, SqlConnectionIPAddressPreference ipPreference)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SSRP.GetPortByInstanceName(String browserHostName, String instanceName, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean allIPsInParallel, SqlConnectionIPAddressPreference ipPreference)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIProxy.CreateTcpHandle(DataSource details, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean parallel, SqlConnectionIPAddressPreference ipPreference, String cachedFQDN, SQLDNSInfo& pendingDNSInfo, Boolean tlsFirst, String hostNameInCertificate)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIProxy.CreateConnectionHandle(String fullServerName, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Byte[]& instanceName, Byte[][]& spnBuffer, String serverSPN, Boolean flushCache, Boolean async, Boolean parallel, Boolean isIntegratedSecurity, SqlConnectionIPAddressPreference ipPreference, String cachedFQDN, SQLDNSInfo& pendingDNSInfo, Boolean tlsFirst, String hostNameInCertificate)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.TdsParserStateObjectManaged.CreatePhysicalSNIHandle(String serverName, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Byte[]& instanceName, Byte[][]& spnBuffer, Boolean flushCache, Boolean async, Boolean parallel, SqlConnectionIPAddressPreference iPAddressPreference, String cachedFQDN, SQLDNSInfo& pendingDNSInfo, String serverSPN, Boolean isIntegratedSecurity, Boolean tlsFirst, String hostNameInCertificate)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Boolean withFailover)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at ICD.Framework.Data.UnitOfWork.UnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at ICD.Base.BusinessService.ContactTypeService.InsertContactTypeAsync(InsertContactTypeRequest request) in /Users/hmd/Documents/icd/base/ICD.Base.BusinessService/ContactTypeService.cs:line 97
```

and Connection string:

```
"BaseDbContext": "Data Source=172.18.176.74\\SANA;Initial Catalog=SANA;User Id=Sana;password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Persist Security Info=True;"
```

Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: Probably better to show callstack.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I update the question and add `CallStack`

Comment: Yeah, but also the code of `InsertContactTypeAsync`. That's where it all starts.

Comment: Looks like, there is problem with `Dns.GetHostAddresses`, check your connection string. Looked at source code briefly and looks like it is one possible issue in method `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SSRP.SendUDPRequest()`

Comment: Please share your connection string!

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I shared `ConnectionString`

Comment: @ErikEJ I shared `ConnectionString`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv
@ErikEJ Please consider every thing is ok on `Windows` OS. when I run the program on `Mac M1` the problem occurs. if the error is about connection string so it should be problematic on either `Windows` and `Mac M1`. i guess the problem is related to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` that does not fit on `Mac M1` architecture

Comment: ErikEJ is maintainer of this library, he may help. And actually there is problem exactly in code for Mac. Try to call `Dns.GetHostAddresses("172.18.176.74")` and check what it returns in your application.

Comment: IIRC there's a bug in the implementation of `Dns.GetHostAddress` on the Mac, which might cause this to return null in case of an error.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I found the solution. check the answer. its appreciate you leave comment for my answer

Comment: @ErikEJ I found the solution. check the answer. its appreciate you leave comment for my answer